# Ordenação de dados Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Tenho uma [tabela .cvs](https://blog.jardel.seg.br/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/employee_billing.csv) e preciso

Imprimir o funcionário com o maior valor faturado em cada mês, incluindo nome do funcionário e total (exemplo: "Agosto de 2020 - João - Total Faturado: 150");

Consegui com o código abaixo chegar próximo disso.

Imagem: https://prnt.sc/xidwq9

```
# Read File
df = pd.read_csv('https://..../employee_billing.csv',sep=';')
df['Month'] = pd.Categorical(df['Month'],categories=["Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Nov", "Dec"],ordered=True)
df = df.sort_values(by=['Month', 'Day', 'Year'])
group = df.groupby(["Month", "Year", "Nome"]).sum()
billed = group["Billed"].groupby(level=0, group_keys=False)
billed.nlargest(1)
print(billed.nlargest(1))
```

Mas não consigo colocar o Total Faturado (Billed Total) na ultima coluna.

Comment: HouseKore, boa tarde! Disponibilize dados para teste, desta forma as pessoas podem te ajudar de uma maneira mais fácil. Abraço!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não sei se existe um passo único para fazer isso, mas com dois seria:

### Agrupar por Month e Nome e somar Billed

```
>>> df1 = df.groupby(["Month","Nome"])["Billed"].sum()

>>> df1

Month  Nome
Apr    Billy     18
       John      80
       Laura    112
       Mike     215
       Paul     250
       Sandy     60
Aug    Craig     20
       John     120
       Kate      62
       Laura    166
       Mike      70
Dec    Craig     49
       John     345
(...)
```

### Pegar o maior de cada grupo

```
>>> df2 = df1.loc[df1.groupby(level=0).idxmax()]

>>> df2

Month  Nome
Apr    Paul     250
Aug    Laura    166
Dec    John     345
Jul    Billy    205
Jun    Tom      210
May    Sandy    319
Nov    Craig    280
Sep    Mike     338
Name: Billed, dtype: int64
```

**Update**

O resultado gerado é do tipo Series

### Para nomear a coluna de dados

```
>>> df3 = pd.DataFrame(df2, columns=["Billed"])

>>> df3

             Billed
Month Nome
Apr   Paul      250
Aug   Laura     166
Dec   John      345
Jul   Billy     205
Jun   Tom       210
May   Sandy     319
Nov   Craig     280
Sep   Mike      338
```

**Nota** As colunas Month e Nome são índices.

Para transformá-las em colunas use

```
>>> df3.reset_index(inplace=True)

>>> df3
  Month   Nome  Billed
0   Apr   Paul     250
1   Aug  Laura     166
2   Dec   John     345
3   Jul  Billy     205
4   Jun    Tom     210
5   May  Sandy     319
6   Nov  Craig     280
7   Sep   Mike     338
```

Caso queira renomear a coluna para outro nome use:

```
>>> df3.rename(columns={"Billed": "Total Billed"}, inplace=True)

>>> df3
  Month   Nome  Total Billed
0   Apr   Paul           250
1   Aug  Laura           166
2   Dec   John           345
3   Jul  Billy           205
4   Jun    Tom           210
5   May  Sandy           319
6   Nov  Craig           280
7   Sep   Mike           338
```

**Em tempo**: talvez tenha uma forma mais direta de fazer tudo isso...

Espero que ajude

Comment: Muito obrigado Paulo, eu consegui também essa saida. Seria possível colocar na ultima coluna o nome "Total Billed", por exemplo?

Comment: Atualizei a resposta